# How to simplify conditional Lambda using Switch

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5, switch-statement

Somebody that could point me into the right direction in order to simplify the following code using switch statement?

```
 var indicators = db.Sses
           .GroupBy(x => x.Estado)
           .Select(x => new IndicatorViewModel
           {
               Count = x.Count(),
               IndicatorType = x.Key.ToString(),
               IndicatorClass = 
               EstadoServicio.Nuevo == x.Key ? "bg-red" : 
               (EstadoServicio.Proceso == x.Key ? "bg-yellow" : 
               (EstadoServicio.Aprobación == x.Key ? "bg-aqua" : "bg-green"))
           ,
               IconClass =
                EstadoServicio.Nuevo == x.Key ? "fa-bookmark-o" :
               (EstadoServicio.Proceso == x.Key ? "fa-bell-o" :
               (EstadoServicio.Aprobación == x.Key ? "fa-calendar-o" : "fa-heart-o")),
               Total = x.Count()/total
           });
```

Comment: I say it's simplified right now. Why want `switch`?

Comment: Just foreseeing future maintenance as different Status scales more and more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, if you want to use switch case:

```
        var indicators = db.Sses
            .GroupBy(x => x.Estado)
            .Select(
                delegate(YOUR_TYPE x)
                {
                    var ivm = new IndicatorViewModel
                    {
                        Count = x.Count(),
                        IndicatorType = x.Key.ToString(),
                        Total = x.Count()/total
                    };

                    switch (x.Key)
                    {
                        case "bg-red":
                            ivm.IndicatorClass = EstadoServicio.Nuevo;
                            //ivm.IonClass = 
                            break;

                        // etc.
                    }

                    return ivm;
                }
            );
```

Comment: The type of parameter 'x'. If you are not sure what it is, try to move with mouse over it in your own lamda expression. VS should displsy it.

Comment: X represents my DataSet or Table, however, it hasn't any fields named Count nor Key as they are only shown on my ViewModel.... in other words, when I use my type "table", the fields Count and Key are not recognized anymore

Comment: GroupBy returns normally IENumerable<IGrouping<T1,T2>>. Move on GroupBy method with mouse. It should be the type for your param than.

Comment: I really appreciate your kind help, moller111. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much moller1111... I've figure it out with your help!
This is the final working code in case somebody else need it:

```
            var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        int total = db.Sses.Count();

        var indicators = db.Sses
        .GroupBy(x => x.Estado)
        .Select(
        delegate(IGrouping<EstadoServicio,Ss> x)
        {
            var ivm = new IndicatorViewModel
            {
                Count = x.Count(),
                IndicatorType = x.Key.ToString(),
                Total = total
            };

            switch (x.Key)
            {
                case EstadoServicio.Nuevo:
                    ivm.IndicatorClass = "bg-red";
                    ivm.IconClass = "fa-bookmark-o";
                    break;

                case EstadoServicio.Proceso:
                    ivm.IndicatorClass = "bg-yellow";
                    ivm.IconClass = "fa-bell-o";
                    break;

                case EstadoServicio.Aprobación:
                    ivm.IndicatorClass = "bg-aqua";
                    ivm.IconClass = "fa-calendar-o";
                    break;

                default:
                    ivm.IndicatorClass = "bg-green";
                    ivm.IconClass = "fa-heart-o";
                    break;
            }

            return ivm;
        }
);
```