# Switch Statement in Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, switch-statement

I have the following code in my HomeController:

```cs
public ActionResult Phones_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request) {
  var result = new DataSourceResult();           
  using (var context = new GPEContext()) {
    var filterzzz = context.TelefonUndAbwesends.Where(p => !p.Name.Contains("zzz"));
    IQueryable < TelefonUndAbwesend > telListe = filterzzz;                    
    result = telListe.ToDataSourceResult(request);                                    
    return Json(result);
  }
}
```

How can I use additional to the filterzzz variable a switch statement? I have multiple switch scenerios for p.Status:

```cs
switch(p.Status) {
  case "0":
    p.Status = "Abwesend";
    break;
  case "1":
    p.Status = "Anwesend";
    break;
  case "2":
    p.Status = "Pause";
    break;
  case "3":
    p.Status = "Dienstgang";
    break;
  case "4":
    p.Status = "Home Office";
    break;
  default:
    p.Status = "";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to map the `Status` in the `result`?

Comment: Inside a `foreach` through that `result`? That code block isn't *required* to go into a linq statement

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. @juharr -> yes i want to map the Status in the result. I need to filter the Names prop and the Status. I archived that with the Names in the var filterzzz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Thanks to this post. [Klick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128888/how-to-simplify-conditional-lambda-using-switch)

```
var filterzzz = context.TelefonUndAbwesends.Where(p => !p.Name.Contains("zzz"))
                .Select(
                    delegate (TelefonUndAbwesend p)
                    {
                        var switchedList = new TelefonUndAbwesend
                        {
                            Name = p.Name,
                            Abteilung = p.Abteilung,
                            Durchwahl = p.Durchwahl,
                            Kürzel = p.Kürzel

                        };

                        switch (p.Status)
                        {
                            case "0":
                                switchedList.Status = "Abwesend";
                                break;
                            case "1":
                                switchedList.Status = "Anwesend";
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                switchedList.Status = "Pause";
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                switchedList.Status = "Dienstgang";
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                switchedList.Status = "Home Office";
                                break;
                            default:
                                switchedList.Status = "";
                                break;
                        }
                        return switchedList;
                    }).AsQueryable();
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Ouch, that's ugly. I'd make a model that you set the status, and the logic for the switch is in a readonly property called "StatusDescription" or something like that. Or just extend TelefonUndAbwesend with the added property.